# How to write output to Excel from robotium?

Tags: android, eclipse, excel, robotium

I have used POI to write output to Excel. My code is working perfectly in a normal Android application. But when I run the application as android j unit writing to Excel functionality is not working.Here is the condition I use in the robotium test project

```
if (solo.getButton("Submit").isShown()){

     new TestResult().resultToExcel("/mnt/sdcard/Test_output.xls",0, "TC_memory1", "passed","testcase passed",6);
}
else
{
     new TestResult().resultToExcel("/mnt/sdcard/Test_output.xls",0, "TC_memory1", "failed","testcase failed",6);
}
```

Could any one suggest a method to write output to an excel file by using robotium.

Comment: What exactly happens? Does it just not write anything? Does it throw an error?

Comment: no error, its just does not write anything. When i use the code to run a normal android application it works perfectly

Comment: issues was because of not adding uses permission in manifest file. Issue resolved

Comment: That makes sense but i assumed it must have been something weirder because you claimed there was no error (This would of shown in logcat) and that it worked in the android application (which i assumed was the AUT and it is this manifest file which your instrumentation test actually uses). Glad its all fixed for you now though.

Comment: yes its working perfectly now..anyway thanks for looking up